# Sigma-ideal of meagre sets vs. ideal of nowhere dense sets

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

Givant and Halmos state p. 379 of their *Introduction to Boolean Algebra*:

> The class of Baire sets of a $\sigma$-space is a $\sigma$-algebra, by definition. The subclass of meager Baire sets is naturally a $\sigma$-ideal in that algebra. It turns out that Baire sets are almost clopen sets in the sense that each Baire set differs symmetrically from a uniquely determined clopen set by a meager Baire set.

Since the meagre set in question is the boundary of some Baire set (which is even nowhere dense), why do we consider equivalence classes of Baire sets modulo the $\sigma$-ideal of meagre sets instead of equivalence classes of Baire sets modulo the ideal of nowhere dense sets?

Is it because in order that $\textrm{Ba}(X)/M$ be a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra (where $\textrm{Ba}(X)$ is the $\sigma$-field of Baire subsets of $X$), $M$ must necessarily be a $\sigma$-ideal?

Comment: Boundaries of Baire sets are not necessarily nowhere dense: $\Bbb C$ (the Cantor set) is the boundary of the Baire set $Q$ (a countable dense subset of $\Bbb C$, e.g. the endpoints) e.g. (singletons are in the Baire $\sigma$-algebra)

Comment: But the Cantor set is nowhere dense @HennoBrandsma?

Comment: The Cantor set is $ X$, the whole space.

Comment: Could you please expand a little for I am not sure I fully understand @HennoBrandsma

Comment: $X$, the Cantor set, has a countable dense subset $Q$, say. In $X$ Borel sets and Baire sets are the same. $Q$ is in the $\sigma$-ideal of meagre Baire sets but its boundary is $X$ which is not nowhere dense in $X$ as you claimed.

Comment: And of course in a $\sigma$-algebra we mod out by $\sigma$-ideals to preserve the countable operations.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: Why is $X$ not nowhere dense in $X$?

Comment: Its interior is not empty (it’s $X$). Trivial.